# Oreo Heads up notification - how to detect/ intercept user swiping notification to status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

Using `NotificationCompat.Builder`, I am creating a incoming call notification, `PRIORITY_HIGH` notification with vibrate and ongoing set to true.

When `notify()` is called it also starts the ringtone player, playing the ringtone.

Currently this works perfectly. The answer and decline actions work fine, the only nuance is if you swipe away the notification, its demoted to the status bar (that is fine) but I also want the ringtone player to stop at this point.

Is there a way I can be told, or tell that the heads up notification has been swiped up into the status bar?

**Answer in comment to accepted answer.**

Problem was resolved by adding ringtone to the builder with .setSound(). Thanks A.A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is a [deleteIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#deleteintent)

> *deleteIntent*
>
> The intent to execute when the notification is explicitly dismissed by the user, either with the "Clear All" button or by swiping it away individually. This probably shouldn't be launching an activity since several of those will be sent at the same time.

You can set the `PendingIntent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` and then perform any action you want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this):
builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);
```

And for the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // stop your ringtone here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this. setDeleteIntent is only triggered when swiped away in the status tray. It doesnt seem to work when swiping the heads up into the tray.

Comment: i see.. how did you set the ringtone for the notifications?

Comment: Nothing complicated, I grab the Default ringtone from RingtoneManager then ringtonePlayer.start(defaultRingtone); when notify() is called.

Its not bound to the notification.

Comment: why don't you just use [NotificationCompat.Builder#setSound](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri))?

Comment: I have no idea how I missed this. Well, now I feel stupid haha. Thanks!